# Tooltip on border-left CSS element

Tags: css, razor, tooltip

We have a list of items and each item has a color at the edge to indicate its type. We now want to have a tooltip on that edge color that show what type of item it is. It is easy to set a tooltip for the entire row, but that is not what we want to do because we just want to explain what the color code means.

The edge color is set using a border-left, the green part to the left in the image below.

```
my-request.aRequestType, tr.my-request td:first-child {
    border-left: 10px solid #757e4b;
}
```

Is there a way to set a tooltip that just applies to a border-left area?
We want to set this different for each row, so just setting the same on all border-left doesn't work.

The application is built using .NET 6, Razor and Bootstrap 3.3.

[image]

Comment: why don't you start by looking and share what's going on your browser code inspector.... ?

Comment: Instead of just trying the left border, insert an element just outside or inside that border and have the tooltip on that.

Comment: @MisterJojo, I did just that. I took the definition from dev tools. I don't see the need for all the nested div that builds the row.

Comment: and what about your HTML element with the tagName `<my-request>` ?

Comment: @sativay, yes that is an option. But one I have been unable look good due to my limited front-end skills. So I was hoping it would be possible to do something smart with the border-left. I'm maintaining an application, did not write it to start with.

Comment: @MisterJojo It is a <div class="row my-request aRequestType assignmentSelectable">...</div>

Comment: for your css it is a custom element. `<my-request class="aRequestType"` --> `my-request.aRequestType,` I think it is a typo, you missed a point.